# href argument of anchor tag is not getting passed

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, thymeleaf

So I am trying to send an email using `JavaMailSender`, `MimeMessage` and `MimeMessageHelper` and add an unsubscribe clickable link to the end of the mail. This is my `MailService` method

```
package com.emailScheduler.emailScheduler.Service;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.mail.SimpleMailMessage;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.MimeMessageHelper;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.thymeleaf.spring5.SpringTemplateEngine;

import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

@Service
public class MailService {

    @Autowired
    private JavaMailSender javaMailSender;

    @Autowired
    private SpringTemplateEngine springTemplateEngine;

    //Simple mail sender method
    public void sendMail(String to, String sub, String msg){
        SimpleMailMessage mailMessage = new SimpleMailMessage();

        mailMessage.setFrom("Sender Name");
        mailMessage.setTo(to);
        mailMessage.setSubject(sub);
        mailMessage.setText(msg);

        javaMailSender.send(mailMessage);
    }

    //HTML mail sender method
    public void sendMail2 (String to, String sub, String msg) throws MessagingException, UnsupportedEncodingException {

        MimeMessage mailMessage = javaMailSender.createMimeMessage();
        MimeMessageHelper messageHelper = new MimeMessageHelper(mailMessage);

        /*Context context = new Context();
        context.setVariables(mailModel);*/

        String html =  "<p>" + msg + "</p>" + "<a href= \"localhost:8080/unsubscribe\">unsubscribe1</a>";
        String html2 = "<p>" + msg + "</p>" + "<a href= 'localhost:8080/unsubscribe'>unsubscribe2</a>";
        String html3 = html + html2;

        messageHelper.setFrom("senderemail@gmail.com", "Sender Name");
        messageHelper.setTo(to);
        messageHelper.setSubject(sub);
        messageHelper.setText(html3, true);

        System.out.println(html);
        System.out.println(html2);

        javaMailSender.send(mailMessage);
    }
}
```

I can successfully send the eamil but in my mail body for some reason `unsubscribe`  is not shown as hyperlink but plain text, on inspecting in chrome browser's inspect element it shows like this `<a>unsubscribe1</a>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the http or https scheme in the hyperlink URL.
only in the case of localhost:8080 or localhost:80 or any other port, Gmail is making HTML email to text. domain.com and other domains will also work without a scheme.

**HTML and body tags are optional.**

```
String html =  "<html><body><p>" + msg + "</p>" + "<a href= 'http://localhost:8080'>unsubscribe1</a>";
        String html2 = "<p>" + msg + "</p>" + "<a href= 'http://localhost:8080'>unsubscribe2</a></body></html>";
        String html3 = html + html2;
```

[image: email with hyperlink]

Comment: Adding ```http``` scheme before the ```localhost:8080/...``` worked for me. Thanks for an explanation and a solution

Answer (score 0):

Try using only ' instead of doing escape char = "

Comment: I have tried both ```'``` and ```"``` neither of them worked

Comment: Try using different link and maybe try using msg without <p> tag